# RSS+SSL (gmail) via command line?

Tags: rss, gmail

My goal is to be able to read new messages from a gmail account via a linux server. I guess I could do this via IMAP or something, but I'd like to avoid that complexity if possible given that gmail has this nice feed set up:

https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/

The only issue is that I'm not sure how to authenticate the call to pull this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point should be:

```
curl -u username:password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | tr -d '\n' | awk -F '<entry>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {print $i}}' | sed -n "s/<title>\(.*\)<\/title.*name>\(.*\)<\/name>.*/\2 - \1/p"
```

Checks the Gmail ATOM feed for your account, parses it and outputs a list of unread messages.

Also, see this thread: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3380/check-your-unread-gmail-from-the-command-line

OTOH, I would recommend using `mutt` and IMAP.

Comment: // , This returns a minimal HTML response titled, `UNAUTHORIZED`, and the response contains `Error 401`.